# Put terminal symbol(`$`) inside character group(`[]`)?

Tags: javascript, regex

`/ca|cb/` is same as `/c[a|b]/`.

But when I convert `/.*\n|.*$/` to `/.*[\n|$]/`, the second Regexp doesn't match `'aaa'` while the first does.

So how to make terminal **symbol(`$`)** work in a **character group(`[]`)**?

Comment: `/ca|cb/` is **not** same as `/c[a|b]/`

Comment: `/ca|cb/` yields the same results as `/c[ab]/`, but these patterns differ in effeciency, too.

Comment: You cannot put assertions inside a character group, as they aren't characters.

Comment: Question solved, thank you.